# i was migrating data from oracle to s3 using AWS DMS, DMS is reading LONG datatype as LOB and is skipping the entire column and data

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-migration, aws-dms

I was migrating the data from Oracle DB to AWS S3 using DMS, In the Oracle DB in one of the table the datatype for the column is Long, but the dms while reading and transfering to S3 getting the below message in the Logs, replacing the actual column and table definition names.

Column 'sample_column' was removed from table definition 'sample_table: the column data type is LOB and the table has no primary key or unique index.

But i verified that the source datatype for the sample_column was Long.

How do i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html

> Oracle data type: LONG
>
> AWS DMS data type: CLOB

> The LONG data type isn't supported in batch-optimized apply mode
> (TurboStream CDC mode). To use this data type with AWS DMS, you must
> enable the use of LOBs for a specific task. During CDC, AWS DMS
> supports LOB data types only in tables that have a primary key.

So the type conversion appears to be expected, and the real issue here is that you have no primary key on the table.

Comment: I am using DMS for FullTime Load, will this also applicable for the Full Time Load

Comment: @user9342493 Did you find a workaround?